# compatibility of my html/css code in IE and firefox

Tags: html, css, wordpress

i am beginner word press developer, i have recently added the following code to sidebar of my website, its working fine on Google chrome.But in Firefox and IE the image i have linked is scaled occupying the entire content area.Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
<div>

 <div style="  width: 80%;height: 58%; z-index: -1;  position: fixed; left: -12%; top: 16%;">
    <img src="http://abc.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/untd1.png" style="   width:100%;
height:100%;" alt="" />
</div><div style=" margin-left:59%; width:59%; height:100%; float: right;" >[contact-form-7 id="207" title="sidebar Contact form"]</div></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "width" and "height" attributes from the image tag itself? I'd use CSS to define the dimensions of the image.

Comment: Thank you for your response jnkrois, i tried that,it did not make any change.The image seems to be scrolling with the page scroll and is scaled but only in IE and firefox, its even fine in mobile view.Also the image is not even displayed in opera.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove style "left: -12%;" in the second div (in second line)

Comment: I tried removing that too, the position changed but still the image is scrolling with the page scroll.

Comment: if is image scrolling with page scroll you have to remove position: fixed... Maybe I understood wrong at first time..

Comment: My purpose was to place an image next to the contact form, contact form is a plugin, so it scales with screen size inorder to compensate with the form i added position:fixed.so if i removed that it may come to position but will not satisfy the requirement.

Comment: I also tried this code, but in this the image was not maintaining the equivalent size as with the form '<div style="position: relative; width:auto;height:250px">
<div style="float:left;"><img style="margin-right:5px;margin-left:-5%;margin-top:18%;" alt="" src="http://***.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/untd1.png" width="73%" height="200%"  /></div>
<div>
<h6 style="position: absolute; margin-right:10%;margin-left:41%; width:59%; height:100%; float: right;">[contact-form-7 id="207" title="sidebar Contact form"]</h6>
</div>
</div>'

Comment: Contact form has some width in page, you want to add image next to form, only floated ? Can't imagine... Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LecQv/

Comment: yes.i have added the form in the sidebar widget area.but in this the image is appearing on the side right, but i was looking for a small overlap that is why z-index is used.Also image need to be of same size as the form.